# What is the covariant derivative of a wedge product?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

If we have a covariant derivative for vector fields given by an affine connection on a manifold, can we extend that to a covariant derivative for k-vectors by assuming that the product rule hold for wedge products of vectors? In other words, does it make sense to assume that:

$$\nabla_v(a\wedge b) = (\nabla_va)\wedge b+a\wedge (\nabla_vb) $$

where $v$ is a vector field, $a$ and $b$ are $p$-vector and $q$-vector fields, and $\nabla_va$ agrees with the covariant derivative of vectors when $a$ is a vector field?

(I am wondering since the product rule for the *exterior* derivative has a grade-dependent sign in it, but I think that should not be the case here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $\nabla_v (a\wedge b)=(\nabla_v a)\wedge b+a\wedge(\nabla_v b)$ for any $v\in TM$ and $a,b\in\mathcal{T}^{\bullet,0}M$.  This is the Leibniz rule for tensor product, projected down to the alternating parts.  See, for example, [this question](/questions/1445627).

(The $(-1)^k$ sign for exterior derivative comes from "moving $v$ pass other vectors" when impose the constraint $v$ also participate in the antisymmetry.)